# What is ($\Pi^1_1$-CA)${}+{}$BI? And what is ID${}_\omega$?

Tags: logic

What is the formal system ($\Pi^1_1$-CA)${}+{}$BI? And what is ID${}_\omega$, the formal theory of $\omega$-times iterated inductive definitions?

They are both mentioned in the following paper without any further explanations:

W. Buchholz, An independence result for (Pi^1_1-CA)+BI, *Annals of Pure and Applied Logic* 33, 131-155, 1987.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.573.420&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 2):

$\Pi^1_1$-CA + BI is the system $\Pi^1_1$-CA (a subsystem of second order arithmetic called $\Pi^1_1$ comprehension axiom, which is studied in [reverse mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics) ) plus BI which stays for Bar Induction schema

Suppose $\prec$ is a two-place relation symbol defined on a set $X$ and $F(a)$ is an arbitrary $\mathcal{L}_2$-formula. We define:

$Prog(\prec; F) := \forall x[\forall y(y \prec x \rightarrow F(y)) \rightarrow F(x)] \text{(progressiveness)}$

$TI(\prec; F) := Prog(\prec; F) \rightarrow \forall xF(x) \text{(transfinite induction)}$

$WF(\prec) := \displaystyle (\forall S \subseteq X)[S\neq \emptyset \implies (\exists m\in S)(\forall s\in S)\lnot (s\prec m)]\text{(well-foundedness)}$

In other words well-foundedness means that every non-empty subset $S \subseteq X$ has a minimal element with respect to $\prec$.

Bar Induction  is the axiom schema consisting of all formula with the form

$WF(\prec)\rightarrow TI(\prec,F)$

where $\prec$ is an arithmetical relation and $F(a)$ is an arbitrary $\mathcal{L}_2$-formula.

I took this definition from the PhD thesis of Ian Alexander Thomson: [Well-Ordering Principles and $\Pi^1_1$-Comprehension + Bar Induction](http://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/22206/1/ThomsonThesisFinal.pdf) (In this document well-foundedness is defined as $WF(\prec) := \forall YTI(\prec;Y)$, I don't know this definition and I cannot say much about it)

For additional information you can check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_induction) and also this [link](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theory/appendix-c.html) where they provide a definition of bar induction in terms of finite sequences of natural numbers and infinite tree.

ID$_\omega$ is one example of Systems of iterated inductive definitions, a class of formal systems. Check this [link](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/iterated+inductive+definitions) for more details.
You can also check the following book:
*Buchholz, Feferman, Pohlers and Sieg: Iterated inductive definitions and subsystems of analysis: recent proof-theoretical studies, Lecture Notes in Mathematics 897 (1981)*

ID$_\omega$ is proof theoretic equivalent to $\Pi^1_1$-CA + BI (and also to KPl, which is the KP (Kripke–Platek set theory) asserting "the universe is a limit of admissible sets").
Their proof theoretic ordinal is the Takeuti-Feferman–Buchholz  ordinal $\psi_0(\varepsilon_{\Omega_{\omega}+1})$ expressed with the [Buchholz's psi collapsing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchholz_psi_functions).
This ordinal is also the limit of the Buchholz's psi collapsing function notation.

Comment: I don't understant the statement "WF(<) -> TI(<,F)". It says "if the property TI holds for every F, then it holds for a specific F".

Comment: All sources I can find (except for the PhD thesis I mentioned above)  a well founded relation is defines as a relation where every non empty set has a minimal element, and given this definition Bar induction is the schema of   this type $WF(\prec) \rightarrow TI(\prec,F)$. In particular you can find this in the article "The Role of Parameters in Bar Rule and Bar Induction" by Michael Rathjen (the PhD supervisor of Ian Alexander Thomson).

Comment: I  dont know much about this alternative definition of well foundedness and I am not able to provide an explanation about the circularity you point out. I would like to add that I didnt know anything about Bar Induction myself before answering your question, I found your question because I needed  the answer myself and I was frustrated that none of the experts of this website provided an answer so I just gathered the information I could and shared it in the answer.

Comment: last thing in case you didn't notice: I added a link to plato.stanford.edu where they provide a definition of bar induction in terms of finite sequences of natural numbers and infinite tree